# Style of 3 circles progress bar with hover

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to design this 3 circle progress bar. It is supposed to look like this:
https://postimg.org/image/mhnp2krrn/

The green center circle is visible on hover and on click. Then when the progress moves along, the bar looks like this:
https://postimg.org/image/kokse96kz/

I have been stuck and my code for the circles is basically just three circles with on hover effects to turn them green.

```
.step-progress-step .btn-circle {
  background: #f1f1f2;
  border-color: #b3b3b3;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}


.step-progress-step .btn-circle:hover {
  background: #01c966;
}
```

This is my code for the line that wont even appear. I was trying to make it red to see it. The line is there, but not visible. I can't find any CSS styling that is preventing me from seeing it. The positioning is not relevant, this code was grabbed from another project where the line needed to be displayed at that spot.

```
.step-progress-row:before {
  top: 19px;
  left: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 75%;
  height: 1px;
  color: red;
  z-index: -2;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
```

My HTML:

```
                <div class="btn-circle-row row">
                  <div class="col l12">
                    <div class="step-progress {{progress.step}}">
                      <div class="step-progress-row">
                        <div class="step-progress-step col l6">
                          <div class="btn-default btn-circle"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="step-progress-step col l6">
                          <div class="btn-default btn-circle"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

If anyone could help me, that would be awesome.

Comment: Instead of verbally describing your code, please post the actual code. I.e. the parts that are not there but are still mentioned.

Comment: I thought i included everything. I added the on hover. i'm not sure what else is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `background-color: red;` instead of `color: red;` for your .step-progress-row:before and I think you'll see your line.
See here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEgwgp